# Delphi get Logical drives

Tags: delphi, winapi

I need to get all logical drives in delphi into TStringList.IHave no idea how to do it.I tried to use drive combobox,but it caused acess violation(after porcedure was ended)

Comment: Doing a quick search on the Internet yields thousands of answers. What have you done? Do you have some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows, have a look at [`TDirectory.GetLogicalDrives`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetLogicalDrives) (returns a string array).